# Creating a new line of text below the existing one when setting the white-space property back to normal

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a Google imitation project. Currently, I'm making the apps menu:
[Screenshot of the menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AF2Is.png)

If the name of the google service is long enough to occupy two lines, then just the first line will be shown with some ellipsis, like this:
[Service's name occupying one line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsFwF.png)

If you hover over the service, then the text will be shown completely, like this:
[Service name complete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hhi5A.png)

To imitate this effect, I put the image, within a div, and the text in a wrapper with the class name app-container, creating the following HTML:

```
                <div class="google-apps-menu-container">
                    <ul class="google-apps-menu">
                        <li class="app-container">
                            <div class="img-app-container"><img src="images/applogos/profile-photo.svg" alt="" id="user-profile-picture-for-apps" class="app-logo"></div>
                            <p class="app-name">Cuenta</p>
                        </li>
                        <li class="app-container">
                            <div class="img-app-container"><img src="images/applogos/search.svg" alt="" class="app-logo"></div>
                            <p class="app-name">Búsquda</p>
                        </li>
                        <li class="app-container">
                            <div class="img-app-container"><img src="images/applogos/bussisnes-logo.svg" alt="" class="app-logo"></div>
                            <p class="app-name">Perfil de Empresa</p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

To achieve the text abbreviation described before, I have the following CSS applied to the paragraph with the name of the service:

```
.app-name
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 11ch;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Whenever you hover over the service name, I just set the white-space property to normal. It works. However, it creates a second line of text above the existing one and not below as the google web page does:

[The second line of the paragraph is created below the existing one (As I want)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xSPM.png)

[The second line of the paragraph is created above the existing one (As I don't want to)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BptZF.png)

I have to say that the paragraph in which the name of the service is has a position property of "absolute", whereas the wrapper of the image is just an element centered in a flexbox display.

Please, help me to solve the issue.

If you need any extra information, please tell me. It's my first time posting a question in stack overflow, so I apologize if something is wrong with the post.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please provide more code

Answer (score 0):

Using your snippets as a starting point I was able to reproduce the error. In my case, swapping `bottom: 0` to `top: 0` fixed the alignment.

````
<head>
    <style>
            .google-apps-menu-container
            {
                background-color: red;
            }
            .google-apps-menu
            {
                background-color: blue;
                display: inline-block;
            }
            .app-container
            {
                width: 50;
                height: 50;
                display: inline-block;
                position: relative;
            }
            .app-name
            {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                text-align: center;
                max-width: 11ch;
                overflow: hidden;
                /* white-space: nowrap; */
                text-overflow: ellipsis;
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="google-apps-menu-container">
        <ul class="google-apps-menu">
            <li class="app-container">
                <div class="img-app-container"><img src="images/applogos/profile-photo.svg" alt="" id="user-profile-picture-for-apps" class="app-logo"></div>
                <p class="app-name">Cuenta</p>
            </li>
            <li class="app-container">
                <div class="img-app-container"><img src="images/applogos/search.svg" alt="" class="app-logo"></div>
                <p class="app-name">Búsquda</p>
            </li>
            <li class="app-container">
                <div class="img-app-container"><img src="images/applogos/bussisnes-logo.svg" alt="" class="app-logo"></div>
                <p class="app-name">Perfil de Empresa</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

What you need is actually very easy. Just make all icons the same height and add text below icons. Do not use position absolute, just basic layout with flex.

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  padding: .5rem;
  background-color: #222;
  color: #fff;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.col {
  width: 70px;
  padding: .5rem;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}

.col:hover {
  background-color: #666;
}

.icon {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  margin-bottom: .25rem;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.text {
  border: 1px solid pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  
    <div class="col">
      <div class="icon">ICON</div>
      <div class="text">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
      <div class="icon">ICON</div>
      <div class="text">Lorem</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
      <div class="icon">ICON</div>
      <div class="text">Lorem</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
      <div class="icon">ICON</div>
      <div class="text">Lorem</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
      <div class="icon">ICON</div>
      <div class="text">Lorem</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
      <div class="icon">ICON</div>
      <div class="text">Lorem</div>
    </div>
  
  </div>
</div>
```